# Definition of a Firebase rule

Tags: firebase, web-applications, rules

Despite my research on the web, I cannot figure out how to set up a firebase rule so that access to my data is only possible for users of my web application.
Can someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Firebase consists of 18 or so products, 3 of which currently support setting up security rules to control access to them. Please edit your question to be more specific about what product you are trying to protect, and what you've already tried. I also recommend checking out https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check

Comment: This is a firestore database.
The definition of security rules is as follows:
rules_version = '2';
cloud.firestore service {
  match / databases / {database} / documents {
    match / {document = **} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
I would like access to be given only to users of my web application. So undoubtedly protection by domain name.

Comment: That's all great information to have. Can you set the specific product(s) you're asking about in the tags of your question, and the rules (if they're relevant) formatted in your question body? --- Also: did you check the link?